# Adding MouseMotionListener to paddle (Java Pong Game)

Tags: java, jframe, mouselistener, pong

I searched the entire web trying to find a solution but in the end i just ended up being much more confused and frustrated. I am trying to get my paddle to move (paddle_y). Paddle does not need an x coordinate and it just has to move up and down on the vertical line. I have no idea what syntax i need for the mouseListener to get my paddle to move. please provide an example or solution if possible. Thanks a ton, any help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class PongGame extends JFrame implements Runnable, MouseMotionListener {


  int ball_x, ball_y, ball_dx, ball_dy;
  int ball_r;

  int x_left, x_right, y_top, y_bottom;

  int paddle_y = 30;


  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  public PongGame(){
    init();
  }

  /**
   *  UI
   */
  protected void init(){
    this.setSize(300,300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     


    int curX = -1, curY = -1;

    ball_x = this.getWidth()/2;
    ball_y = this.getHeight()/2;

    ball_dx = ball_dy = 2;

    ball_r = 20;

    this.setVisible(true);
    getFocus(this);

    x_left = this.getInsets().left;
    x_right = this.getWidth() - this.getInsets().right - ball_r;
    y_top = this.getHeight() - this.getInsets().top + ball_r/3;
    y_bottom = this.getInsets().bottom + ball_r;

    addMouseMotionListener(this);

  }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

       //help
    }


    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
      //help
    }


  /**
   * helper method which we use to get the focus
   */
  public void getFocus(final JFrame frame)
  {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  frame.requestFocus();
              }
       });
  }

  /**
   * implementation of the Runnable interface to be able to move the ball, etc.
   */
  public void run(){

    while(true){

      ball_x += ball_dx;
      if(ball_x <= x_left || ball_x >= x_right){
        ball_dx *=-1;
        ball_x += (2*ball_dx);
      }

      ball_y += ball_dy;
      if(ball_y <= y_bottom || ball_y >= y_top){
        ball_dy *=-1;
        ball_y += (2*ball_dy);
      }

      repaint();

      try{
        Thread.sleep(50);
      }catch(InterruptedException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * all rendering occurs here
   */
  public void paint(Graphics g){

    //Color paddleOne;
    //paddleOne = new Color(0);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval(ball_x,ball_y, ball_r, ball_r);

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0,paddle_y,20,70);
  }

  /**
   * entry point into the program
   */
  public static void main(String[] args){
    // create the class
    PongGame application = new PongGame();
    new Thread(application).start();

  }

}
```

paddle:

```
int paddle_y = 30;



g.setColor(Color.black);
g.fillRect(0,paddle_y,20,70);




 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

       //help
    }


    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
      //help
    }
```

Comment: Hey you can go here and get everything. https://github.com/Jaryt23/PongTutorial/tree/master/pong

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation for MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html).  Do any of those methods look like they might provide data you can use to modify the value of your `paddle_y` field?

Comment: I'll take a look at those documents. thanks a lot. much appreciated.

Comment: not what i was looking for, although it helped alot. PongTutorial is definitely going to be helpful in the future. I already looked at the doc for the mouse event but it didnt help me much.

Comment: `the doc for the mouse event but it didnt help me much.`, Basically you need to keep the last MouseEvent and the current MouseEvent. Then you can compare the change in the "Y" value. Then you update your paddle_y value by the difference and invoke repaint(). Of course you should NOT be overriding the paint() method of a JFrame. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame.

Comment: @camickr thanks, i'll try that but i would really appreciate an example if possible. I am new to writing in java, im not very familiar with the syntax.

Comment: And you learn by trying. So the first thing you do is add code to the mouseDragged() method to display the mouse point. That is a simple example of listener. You can also read the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) for a working example. Or you can search the forum or web for examples that implement the mouseDragged() method. The resources are there, take advantage of them. If you have problems then you can post your code and I might be able to help, but only if you make an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Paddle` class needs an instance of the `JFrame` class in order to add a mouse listener. If you pass a `JFrame` object into the constructor, you can then use the following code:

```
public class Paddle {
    private JFrame frame;
    private int paddle_y;
    public Paddle(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.paddle_y = 30; //Or whatever number you want
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                Paddle.this.paddle_y = e.getY(); //When the mouse is moved, it will call on this function to change the Paddle.paddle_y variable.
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){} //This reacts when the mouse is clicked, moved, then released.
    }
}
```

This should replace the Paddle class, and it should change the paddle_y variable when the mouse is moved.

**EDIT**: If you do not want to create a new class, put this into the JFrame class:

```
int paddle_y;
this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    paddle_y = e.getY(); //When the mouse is moved, it will call on this function to change the paddle_y variable (Within the JFrame class).
                }
```

Then you can call on the paddle_y variable when rendering.

Comment: im trying to add this without a class but im facing alot of errors. any idea how to do it without a new class?